# error The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: centos, php, laravel, whm

after change server and setup centos with cpanel
lumen cron job not worked and every minutes add this error to lumen log:

**The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation**. in /home/username/public_html/api/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:143

i see active php version ini and remove proc_open from disabled function and restart litespeed but not fix this problem
i change lumen config but not fix . if you now how can i solve this problem pls help me .

Comment: Questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply. Some related topics may be asked on Webmasters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find solation for my problem
i change cronjob in cpanel
(the best php versin after remove this function from php.ini for me was 7.4ea)

then
i change cronjob command in cpanel to: (you can change ea-php74 to custom version)

```
/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/yourusername/public_html/api/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null
```

have good time :D